# Do pointers die after function ends?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
void add_first(int e) {
        Node* newest = new Node(e, first);
        first = newest;
        n++;
}
```

On this code i declared a node pointer "newest".

```
list->add_first(4);
```

Let's say i call that function for the second time.

```
list->add_first(8)
```

Is it still that same *newest from the first time i called the function pointing at a new node OR did the previous *newest die after the function and on the second function call a new *newest was generated?

**//Full code in case you need extra information**

```
template <typename T>
class List {
    struct Node {
        T elem;
        Node* next;

        Node(T elem = 0, Node* next = nullptr) : elem(elem), next(next) {}
    };

    Node* first;
    size_t n;

public:
    List () : n(0), first(nullptr) {}
    ~List () {
        while (first != nullptr) {
            Node* aux = first;
            first = first->next;
            delete aux;
        }
    }

    bool addFirst(T e) {
        Node* newest = new Node(e, first);
        first = newest;
        n++;
        return true;
    }
    bool add(T e, size_t p) {
        if (p > n) return false;
        if (p == 0) return addFirst(e);

        Node* newest = new Node(e);

        Node* aux = first;
        size_t i = 1;
        while (i++ < p) {
            aux = aux->next;
        }
        newest->next = aux->next;
        aux->next = newest;
        n++;
        return true;
    }
    bool addLast(T e) {
        return add(e, n);
    }
};
```

Comment: In your example the pointers do die, but the memory address they store remain allocated.

Comment: You should probably pick up [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) - everything will be explained there

Comment: So the second time i call the function it's actually a new *newest? ok thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
new Node(e, first)
```

will allocate new memory on the heap for an object of type `Node`, where it will remain until you manually deallocate it using `delete`. If you don't retain a reference to it, then you can't deallocate it and you have a memory leak.

```
Node* newest = ...;
```

will create a pointer of type `Node` on the stack until it goes out of scope (in this case, when the function returns), initializing it to reference the object you just created.

It's important to note that `newest` is *not* the object; it is merely referencing it for the time being.

```
first = newest;
```

The type of `first` is not provided here, but presumably in order for it to compile it is defined at a higher scope, e.g. a member variable, and accepts an assignment of type `Node*`...so it's probably a `Node*` itself.

In which case this will by default set `first` to reference the same object pointed to by `newest`. It is *not* pointing to `newest` in this scenario, but both are now referencing the same object.

When the function returns, `newest`(the pointer) will be destroyed because it is defined within the scope of the function invocation, but the `Node` object you created will live on the heap, as well as `first` which references it because it's defined outside this scope.

If you immediately call this function again, e.g. in a loop, you will allocate another object of type `Node`, set `first` to that object, and the object previously pointed to by `first` is now orphaned on the heap without a reference.

EDIT: I did just notice that you pass `first` into the constructor for `Node`, so it's possible you're making a separate connection therein.

Comment: So if: "*first" points "*newest" and "*newest" points a node. After the function ends "*newest" gets deleted and "*first" still points the node?

Comment: Correct, except `first`is never pointing to `newest`. You're executing an assignment on `first` to another pointer, which by default will set `first`'s address reference equal to that of `newest`'s address reference; effectively, you're telling `first` to point to the same object at which `newest` is pointing. You could actually leave `newest` out entirely with the same result by doing: `first = new Node(e, first);`

Answer (score 2):

`newest` (i.e. the pointer) dies when the function returns (because it is a local variable). The next time the function is called, a new `newest` variable is created and destroyed again.

`*newest` (i.e. the object it's pointing to) remains alive until you explicitly `delete` it (because you created it with `new`)

Answer (score 2):

Pointers are just types which hold a memory address of an instance of a specific type. In your example you dynamically allocate memory to store an instance of `Node` using `new` and you store its address to a pointer (notice that `new` returns with a pointer which points to the allocated memory). When the function returns, the pointer "dies", but the allocated memory remains allocated.